# Saving user progress/session activity?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, applet

I am creating a local java programming tutorial applet and was hoping to have several local users on the same computer, I was wondering if there was any way that I can save multiple users progression/session activity on the applet?

I am writing it in Java/Netbeans, If there are other solutions/ways this could be done, I would love to know. Is it possible to use SQLite?

Maybe have the saves of each user within the applet (Load/Save/Delete User), not as a separate file that needs selecting.

> E.G.
>
> User 1 makes a local user save, John for example, so "John Save". John
>   completes 10 out of 50 questions. Saves.
>
> User 2 makes a local user save, Bob for example, so "Bob Save". Bob
>   completes 13 out of 50 questions. Saves.
>
> John selects and loads his save and continues on with the questions
>   etc, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank You, 
Mark Lang

Comment: Applets tend to operate within a tight security sandbox, including not been able to write to the local filesystem. You could store this information on the same server as the applet is hosted

Comment: I am only doing the basic applet at the moment, any idea how I would do stuff from a server/local server such as an SQLite one?
Thanks